# Get items of a menu and a submenu in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there any way I can get the items of a menu element in wordpress and then, iterating with PHP, for each of its elements get again its submenu elements if there's any?

I would like to create a custom list and it seeems to me this is easier than dealing with [the Walker function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_custom_Walker_class).

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items  you can iterate over and match by parent ids to create a array tree or whatever. But the walker is actually easy once you do it once.

Comment: The walker can't deal with submenus properly: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/204509/change-submenu-markup?noredirect=1#comment296688_204509

Comment: This is very similiar https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker. Levels are actually just depth i.e. parents = 0, children 1, children of children 2, etc. Also http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-the-walker-class--wp-25401

Answer (score 2):

I see that the question is old, but this might be a solution to your problem (and others in the future) :)

```
if ( ( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() ) && isset( $locations[ $menu_name ] ) ) {
   $menu_name = 'your-menu-name';

   $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );

   $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);

   $menu_list = '<ul id="menu-' . $menu_name . '">';

   foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
       $title = $menu_item->title;
       $url = $menu_item->url;

       if( $menu_item->menu_item_parent == 0){ // Parent
           $menu_list .= '<li class="parent"><a href="' . $url . '">' . $title . '</a></li>';
       }else{ // Child
           $menu_list .= '<li class="child"><a href="' . $url . '">' . $title . '</a></li>';

       }
   } // END foreach
   $menu_list .= '</ul>';
   echo $menu_list;

} // END if isset
```

This will loop trough the whole menu, and while in the loop, you can create if-statements if there is a parent or a child.

Here is all the avalible data in the `menu_items` object. 
To access them, just do like this in the loop: `$menu_item->menu_order`. That will give you `1`

```
[ID] => 143 
[post_author] => 1 
[post_date] => 2016-11-22 18:44:19 
[post_date_gmt] => 2016-11-22 18:44:19 
[post_content] => 
[post_title] => Parent 1 
[post_excerpt] => 
[post_status] => publish 
[comment_status] => closed 
[ping_status] => closed 
[post_password] => 
[post_name] => parent-1 
[to_ping] => 
[pinged] => 
[post_modified] => 2016-11-22 18:46:19 
[post_modified_gmt] => 2016-11-22 18:46:19 
[post_content_filtered] => 
[post_parent] => 0 
[menu_order] => 1 
[post_type] => nav_menu_item 
[post_mime_type] => 
[comment_count] => 0 
[filter] => raw 
[db_id] => 143 
[menu_item_parent] => 0 
[object_id] => 143 
[object] => custom 
[type] => custom 
[type_label] => Custom Link 
[title] => Parent 1 
[url] => # 
[target] => 
[attr_title] => 
[description] =>
```

The code is from the WordPress docs, you can read more there: [wp_get_nav_menu_items](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/)